# Mark group in regex as optional

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate some values with javascript on my form before sending it. Accepted only digits and one comma or dot. Comma or dot are optional.
For example, values '111', '1.0', '1,0' are valid. And values '1', '.0, '1..' or '1..0' are invalid. So, correct value is a something like float number.

In other words, `digits[optional: one comma or dot]digits` is correct string.

I wrote the following regexp:`/^([0-9]+)[.|,]{0,1}[0-9]+$/`. I works correct, except for one case - when value is single digit.
How can I make my regexp work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/^([0-9]+)([.,][0-9]+)?$/` where I force exactly one dot or comma followed by digits, making that whole (dot/comma digit) part optional.

Also, `[.|,]` matches dot, comma or pipe (`|`). `[.,]` matches just dot and comma.

(The reason your previous regex did not work for single digits was because your pattern needed something to match the first `[0-9]+` *and* the second `[0-9]+` after the dot/comma. You could also do `^([0-9]+)[.,]?[0-9]*$` if you wanted).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/^([0-9]+)([.,][0-9])?$/
```

I assume you need the first parens for capturing. You could make the second pair non-capturing.

Comment: Lokks like yout answer also works, if complete it to `/^([0-9]+)([.,][0-9]+)?$/`. Thanks!